# MariaBD alternative to schema

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to store objects in separate tables. I need to know what tables are used for what object and to avoid name collision I prefix table names with an unique `UUID` so I can associate each object to its tables.

The issue there is I end up with pretty long identifiers, potentially breaking the 64-character length constraint of MariaDB.

Is it possible to organize my database in a way I query something "bigger" than my table to get the tables of my object ? For example when writing `JOIN` statement you use `tableName.columnName` when duplicates can occur. Here I am looking for something like `schemaName.tableName`. I have not been able to find documentation on how to organize a MariaDB database in that fashion.

Comment: Why do you need separate tables for each object or subsets of object? I would guess that having a single table for all of them would be easier. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I store OLAP cubes and they need to be stored in a specific fashion, it is called a star schema. The thing is, every cube I store will have some tables with the same name. Every cube as an UUID and I use it to prefix every of its related table.

Comment: I may have a solution that doesn't involve SQL, I could potentially generate random and short enough table names, but I was curious it there was something on top of a `table` that I could use to organize the database.

Comment: Do _not_ use multiple tables.